# How do I use `results(k(i))` from the first do loop in the second do loop?

Tags: fortran

How do I use `results(k(i))` from the first `do` loop in the second `do` loop? Now I'm getting erroneous results in the second `do` loop.

```
  WRITE(*,*) "Enter PRESSURE,TEMPERATURE"
  READ *,p,t
  WRITE(*,*) "Approximate K values for each component using Wilson's 
  correlation are;"
  do i=1,6
  K = (pc(I)/p)*EXP(5.37*(1+w(I))*(1-(tc(I)/t)))
  write(*,99001)K(i)
  end do

  !.......vapor fraction..............
  do i=1,6
  FV=(Z(I)*(K(i)-1))/((VOLD*(K(i)-1))+1)
  FPV=-(Z(I)*((K(i)-1)**2)/(1+(VOLD*(K(i)-1)))**2)
  write(*,99001)fv,fpv
  end do
  99001 FORMAT (9F15.6)
  END program
```

Comment: You're question is more likely to be answered if you put all the code in to code blocks, rather than just the second half. Also, show what erroneous result you're getting.

Comment: ok thanks.........

Comment: assigning value to the array, not to the individual elements?

Comment: i initially made declarations like:                                                                  
      PC(1)=493.1
      PC(2)=666.4
      PC(3)=706.5
      PC(4)=616.0
      PC(5)=550.6
      PC(6)=488.6 and answers for the first do loop were correct.

Comment: thanks albert, can you show examples please?

Comment: Example of what?

Comment: assigning values to array.

Comment: See any book about Fortran; study this site.

Comment: Please read [ask]. If you are getting erroneous results, show them! And explain why they are wrong and how should correct results look like. [Edit] the question to add more info. Do NOT use comments for important information.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> K = (pc(I)/p)*EXP(5.37*(1+w(I))*(1-(tc(I)/t)))
> ```

If K is an array, I suppose you meant:

```
K(I) = (pc(I)/p)*EXP(5.37*(1+w(I))*(1-(tc(I)/t)))
```

If K is not an array, I suppose it should be.

Comment: @priest so, did you apply this suggestion? Did this answer help you? If yes, you can mark this as "accepted", so it'll be easier for other people with the same issue to find the solution.