# How to sum results from an argument,that come in array form

Tags: fortran, newtons-method

I have this fortran 95 do-loop code which return answers in array form, please how do i find the SUM of the answers (fv) without writing them out, because they're iterative and subject to change. thanks

```
  !.......vapor fraction..............
  do i=1,6
    FV=Z(I)*(K(i)-1)/(VOLD*(K(i)-1)+1)
    write(*,99001)FV
  END DO
```

I saw a similar code where someone did:

```
  Real :: Zi(99),Ki(99),NV,FNV,FPNV
  FNV = 0.
  FPNV = 0.  
  Do i=1,NCOMP
    FNV= FNV + Zi(i)*(Ki(i)-1)/(NV*(Ki(i)-1)+1)
    FPNV = FPNV + (1)*Zi(i)*(Ki(i)-1)**2/((NV*(Ki(i)-1)+1)**2)
  end do
  NV1= NV - (FNV/(-1)*FPNV)
```

Hence the values of `FNV` and `FPNV` are summed up in the `do`..`end do` loop.

Comment: Please show more code. Explain where do you need the sum to be stored or returned.

Comment: study the comments at your previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50544053/how-do-i-use-resultski-from-the-first-do-loop-in-the-second-do-loop) about Fortan usage and how to ask.

Comment: Do not concentrate on the spelling, fix the [tag:fortran] tag and show the the code *inside the question*, not in a comment. It is  much more important than spelling. See [ask].

Comment: Advice to OP: delete the code currently in the question and insert a [mcve], paying particular attention to `M`, `C` and `V`.  Right now the code posted, especially the part beginning *I saw a similar code where someone did* seems to be almost entirely irrelevant to what I think might be the underlying question.  The discipline required to construct the [mcve] will assist you greatly in clarifying your question, you may even figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `FV` is a floating number then you can sum it up this way:

```
!.......vapor fraction..............
FVSUM=0.     ! Initialization of sum
do i=1,6
  FV=Z(I)*(K(i)-1)/(VOLD*(K(i)-1)+1)
  write(*,99001)FV
  FVSUM = FVSUM + FV
end do
write(*,*) 'Sum of FV = ', FVSUM
```

After the loop, the sum is printed to standard output in free format.
Please add the declaration of `FVSUM`:

```
real :: FVSUM
```

and tell me if this answers your question.